# Match as many URL route parameters as possible with path-to-regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, match

I would like a means to match as many URL parameters as possible example

```
/teams/:teamID/players/:playerID/seasons/:seasonID/detail
```

would match anything starting with /teams and match as many parameters present, up to /detail (and only up to)

```
/Giants => { teamID: null, playerID: null, seasonID: null }
/Giants/123 => { teamID: 123, playerID: null, seasonID: null }
/Giants/123/players/ => same as above
/Giants/123/players/456/seasons/2020/detail => { teamId: 123, playerID: 456, seasonID: 2020 }
/Giants/123/players/446/seasons/2020 => same as above
```

and not match

```
/Giants/123/players/456/seasons/2020/detail/12345
```

I'm using [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp).

Comment: Are you using Express?  Or, something else?

Comment: @Brad I'm in a React app and trying to use path-to-regexp (which Express uses to parse URL route patterns I believe)

Comment: @blue18hutthutt In that case, I'd recommend dropping the Node.js tag and mentioning in your question the module.

Comment: Re-opened the question, as given the details in the comments, it's different than the duplicate it was closed as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice library that does exactly what I need, is extremely lite and uses well-tested pieces of Backbone.js to do the pattern matching:

https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/feather-route-matcher

Examples:

```
pattern: '/users/:id' 
url: '/something-else' 
extracted params: nothing, because it won't match

pattern: '/users/:id' 
url: '/users/scrooge-mc-duck' 
extracted params: {id: 'scrooge-mc-duck'}

pattern: '/users/:id' 
url: '/users/47' 
extracted params: {id: '47'}

pattern: '/schools/:schoolId/teachers/:teacherId' 
url: '/schools/richland/teachers/47' 
extracted params: {schoolId: 'richland', teacherId: '47'}
```

This provided me exactly what I wanted and needed

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility of not using regex,  you can probably split the URL into an array using `/` as a separator. Get every element of the array that's after `team` all the way until the `details`.

Comment: Is it not a feasible answer that I got a down vote?